# Passing any argument to jQuery validate success option

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation, jquery-validate

jQuery validate has a success option that allows you to perform operations when a user enters valid form data.  It typically takes the argument of "label" which is a dynamically inserted tag for displaying a success label (like a checkmark).

I can't retrieve siblings of "label" for some reason and it doesn't appear in Firebug.  So I'm wondering how I pass it another parameter.  For instance "element" is a jQuery object of the input element.

I want to do something like this but when I alert element it says "undefined"...else where in jQuery validate, element is used.

```
success: function(element) {
   errorspotholder = element.parents('.rightfields').find('.rederrorx');
   element.removeClass('rederrorx').addClass('norederrorx').qtip('destroy');
            },
```

Comment: Do you have a link to your example page? With qTip in the picture it might be changing a few things about the elements that the validation plugin is storing references to in it's `successList` array.

Comment: Hi Nick!  Thanks for the lead.  I took out the qtip initialization that was in the errorPlacement handler but I still can't access "element" from success (i.e., it still says "undefined").

Comment: found the solution...passed the jQuery object element as a global variable from errorPlacement to success option.  seems to work.  thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

passing the jQuery object element as a global variable from errorPlacement to success worked for me.

see the answer posted on: [JQuery Validation errorPlacement Success vs Failure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2236243/jquery-validation-errorplacement-success-vs-failure/3285409#3285409)